# DATE_PART and Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, datepart, looker

I have a problem when I subtract two date in a function `DATE_PART` in this query.

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(date_trunc('month',sql_activity_days.created_month),'YYYY-MM') AS "sql_activity_days.created_month",
    coalesce(SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN(date_part('day', (sql_activity_days.sale_date + 1) - sql_activity_days.start_date) < 122) 
             THEN sql_activity_days.cad_net_invoiced
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ),0) AS "sql_activity_days.activity_over_122_day_after_signup"
FROM
    camel.f_subscription_touch  AS subscription_touch
    LEFT JOIN sql_activity_days ON subscription_touch.id  = sql_activity_days.customer_id 
    group by date_trunc('month',sql_activity_days.created_month) 
    order by 1 desc limit
500
```

The PostgreSQL database encountered an error while running this query.

> ERROR: function date_part(unknown, integer) does not exist Hint: No
>   function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
>   add explicit type casts. Position: 1340

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument of the [function `date_part`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html) can be either a  `timestamp` or an `interval`.

Your expression `(sql_activity_days.sale_date + 1) - sql_activity_days.start_date` subtracts two `dates`, whose resulting datatype is an integer, hence the error.

The solution to this would be to remove `date_part` and use the expression directly. The difference of two dates always gives the value in days.